I can't save RDD object into text files using PySpark
I am trying to create a Spark program to read the airport data from airport.text file, find all the airports which are located in United States and output the airport's name and city's name to an out_airport_in_usa.text file but I get error codes when using .saveAsTextFileto save the RDD object as a text file for viewing.
Like I can't save and view the RDD data
I created a .py file containing the module/function Utils.COMMA_DELIMITER and I added the directory folder containing this .py file to my PYTHONPATH path so that I can import the module.
My code and error are below:
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
import Utils     #this is the module in the .py file

#Create a function
def splitComma(line: str):    
    splits = Utils.COMMA_DELIMITER.split(line)    
    return "{}, {}".format(splits[1], splits[2])`

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("airports").setMaster("local[*]")   
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)`


#Import dataset and auto-creating an RDD
airports = sc.textFile("airports.text")

#filter the data to find all airports in d USA using a lamda function 
airportsInUSA = airports.filter(lambda line : Utils.COMMA_DELIMITER.split(line)[3] == "\"United States\"")  

airportsNameAndCityNames = airportsInUSA.map(splitComma)

airportsNameAndCityNames.saveAsTextFile("out/airports_in_usa.text")
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\user\Documents\Python Programming\PySpark_for_Big_Data_3.ipynb Cell 18 line 2
      1 # Save output in a new text file
----> 2 airportsNameAndCityNames.saveAsTextFile("out/airports_in_usa.text")
      3 # displays an error

File C:\spark\spark-3.4.2-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\rdd.py:3406, in RDD.saveAsTextFile(self, path, compressionCodecClass)
   3404     keyed._jrdd.map(self.ctx._jvm.BytesToString()).saveAsTextFile(path, compressionCodec)
   3405 else:
-> 3406     keyed._jrdd.map(self.ctx._jvm.BytesToString()).saveAsTextFile(path)

File C:\spark\spark-3.4.2-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File C:\spark\spark-3.4.2-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
...
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...

My software specs:

Python 3.11.8
Pyspark 3.4.2
Spark 3.4.2
Java 17
I use VS Code IDE

